# Toolbar background image wont resize

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, toolbar

I am trying to use a resizable image as my toolbar background image, but for some reason the code will not work.  Here are my image sizes:

```
Missions.png         (320x64)
Missions@2x.png      (640x128)
Missions@3x.png      (1242x195)
```

Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
     toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64);

     UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Missions.png"];
     UIImage *resizableBackground = [backgroundImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
-----[toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:resizableBackground] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; -----------------------------

     [self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}
```

I'm getting a warning on the dashed line at 'resizableBackground' that reads: Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

Comment: [toolbar setBackgroundImage:resizableBackground forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error message says - in that line, you're sending the UIImage class message that expects a string parameter an image. Instead, your code should be

```
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:resizableBackground...
```

A couple of other things though:

- On the line where you set the value of backgroundImage, your call to imageNamed: doesn't need ".png" at the end.
- Your resizable image isn't really resizable: cap insets of 0,0,0,0 don't make sense
- You can make this all easier by using an Asset Catalog. It's a bit less code, a simple call to imageNamed: would return a resizable image

Answer (score 0):

Yeah UIImage imageNamed: takes the name of your image as an NSString

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"missions.png"]
```